# Strange behaviour of update in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing an app that allows the user to enter many (often over 30) pieces of information. How many is chosen by the user. Moreover any one user will have many sets of different such inputs. I want the user to be able to reuse and possibly change previously entered information. For that the app will save all the inputs to a file and read them back in if asked. All this works fine except for one issue: the input value that has the number of different pieces of information the user wants somehow can never be changed, it immediately goes back to the value saved. The one thing that is special about this input is that it appears in a for loop. Here is a toy example:

```
folder="C:/localfolder"

ui <- fluidPage(
   actionButton("savebutton", "Save File"),
   textInput("fname", "Name of File",  placeholder = "example"),
   numericInput("n","n", 1),
   uiOutput("inpts")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  save.inputs=eventReactive(input$savebutton,{
    input.values = reactiveValuesToList(input)
    dump("input.values", paste0(folder, "/", input$fname,".dta"))
  
    })
  
  read.inputs=reactive({
    files=dir(folder)[endsWith(dir(folder),".dta")]
    if( !(paste0(input$fname,".dta") %in% files) ) return(NULL)
    source(paste0(folder, "/", input$fname,".dta"))
    updateNumericInput(session , "n",  value = input.values[["n"]])
    for(i in 1:input$n)  {
     updateTextInput(session, paste0("b", i),  value = input.values[[paste0("Text ", i)]])
    }
  
  })
  
   output$inpts=renderUI({
      out=as.list(1:input$n)
      for(i in 1:input$n)
        out[[i]] =tagList(textInput(paste0("b",i),paste0("Text ",i), "A"))
      out
   })
   
   observe({save.inputs()})
   observe({read.inputs()})
}
```

The first time simply type a name for the file and hit Save File. Then close and restart the app, type the same file name. Changing the text in Text 1 works fine but changing n to (say) 2 does not.

Also, if there is a more elegant way to save the "state" of all the inputs for later use and changes I would be interested in that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eventReactive` for `read.inputs` should fix your numeric issue.  Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("savebutton", "Save File"),
  textInput("fname", "Name of File",  placeholder = "example"),
  actionButton("readbutton", "Read File"),
  numericInput("n","n", 1),
  uiOutput("inpts")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  save.inputs=eventReactive(input$savebutton,{
    input.values = reactiveValuesToList(input)
    dump("input.values", paste0(folder, "/", input$fname,".dta"))
    
  })
  
  read.inputs=eventReactive(input$readbutton,{
    files=dir(folder)[endsWith(dir(folder),".dta")]
    if( !(paste0(input$fname,".dta") %in% files) ) return(NULL)
    source(paste0(folder, "/", input$fname,".dta"))
    updateNumericInput(session , "n",  value = input.values[["n"]])
    for(i in 1:input$n)  {
      updateTextInput(session, paste0("b", i),  value = input.values[[paste0("b", i)]])
    }
    
  })
  
  output$inpts=renderUI({
    out=as.list(1:input$n)
    for(i in 1:input$n)
      out[[i]] =tagList(textInput(paste0("b",i),paste0("Text ",i), "A"))
    out
  })
  
  observe({save.inputs()})
  observe({read.inputs()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that works. I actually had tried that, but I tried so many things I likely had it a bit different and it didn't work then. Anyway thanks!